# Bais Yosef's magid/angel tricked him?

Tags: sources-mekorot, malach-angel, sheker-false, story-identification

I heard (in a few dvar Torahs, though I can't find them now) that the Bais Yosef had recorded that his magid (the angel that taught him) had tricked him, and something like "from this we know that lying has a place in Torah too".

Please help me find the original of the Bais Yosef's recording of this story.

Please correct me if I got something wrong.

Comment: also says Gd tricked Avraham regarding why Sarah laughed

Comment: @ray thank you, but I am looking for the Bais yosef source

Comment: @ray "tricked" might not be the appropriate term in that specific case, since Hashem was the one who informed Avraham of the laughter in the first place...

Comment: Torah lo bshamyim hi... so the fact that the angel tricked a human doesn't have anything to do with Torah. Just comes to show that angels can tell lies

Comment: Sounds more like a demon if u ask me